# Diamond square algorithm, smoothed

Tags: algorithm

I recently started out with the diamond square algorithm and while I have watched many examples, I still have a problem with the noise looking "squary" and not as smooth as I want them to be. (I compare them to noise produced by the perlin noise).

Here is the current code with grayscaled image: [Example in my website](http://doodlemeat.se/ds/)

This is the result I am looking for:

[image]

I have to say that I understand the procedure, but in my example, the code is from a tutorial I found on the internet.

Does you know what is wrong?

Comment: Can you put the relevant code in the question itself, along with a direct link to the image (which a higher-rep user can then inline, like I did with the first image)? Questions, and posts in general, should be self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want square patterns, then don't use diamond-square algorithm. The square patterns is a ["flaw" on the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm), and you likely have done nothing wrong. If you want a smooth pattern, then generate your you should use other generators like Perlin.